# I'm not able to show my fetched data on view

Tags: database, search, datatables, laravel-5.8

I created a view named "attendencedetial" in my database by joining two tables.

I'm fetching data from the "attendencedetial" view, and it is working, but when I pass it to my View in table td through controller function the controller name is "StudentController" and function name is "single_studnet_attendence.

When I try to display data in table td it gives me this error:

> Trying to get property 'std_name' of non-object (View: C:\wamp\www\Attendence_Management_System\resources\views\student\viewattendence.blade.php)

```
class StudentController extends Controller
{
    public function single_studnet_attendence(){
    $user_id =  session()->get('userid');
    $user = DB::table('attendencedetial')->where('std_id',$user_id)->first();
    return  view('student.viewattendence',compact('user'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first

- you have declare the route for this new method route/web.php
- you have used proper variable for your view.

Also put your views code so we can refer it and get proper answer. I think you haven't declare the function this in route that's why it showing error.